# Method for comparing VPS node qualities

Tags: vps, xen

I have 2 VPS's from the same company and both of the VPS's are on different nodes.

Are there any kind of test or utility I can preform to see which one has better connection, load, etc?

Is it possible to know from my end?

Comment: Well, you could use a variety of benchmark scripts, but this could change depending on what the other VPSes on the same machine are doing at any given time.

Comment: Even for XEN? Aren't they isolated?

Comment: You're potentially in contention for things like bandwidth. Your network benchmarking's going to go differently if the other VMs are maxing out a 1Gbps port already.

Comment: In my case, 100Mbps port which is why I'm curious. Besides bandwidth, what else can benchmarks tell about the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can run [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) on your VPS.

*BUT it depends*.

1. Are your VPS on the same physical machine?
2. Are you charged by cpu hour (like Amazon)?
3. Are your disks on the same storage device?
4. Are your VPS on the same network?

The best thing for you to do is open a ticket and ask them to look into the issue. In this ticket ask the technician if your VMs are located on different storage arrays/network/system.

But honestly, it still depends. You're in a shared environment (even though it may seem like you are not), a specific level of service is not guaranteed, only an average level of service is "guaranteed".

Comment: Could you add that as answer to [my question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35447/vm-benchmark-tools), too?